# clear validation message in jquery

Tags: jquery

### I clearing validation message onchange event but , validation message is not being empty.

```
                              <select class="niceSelect" id="guest">
                                                <option value="1">Expected no of guests</option>
                                                <option value="2">0-50</option>
                                                <option value="3">50-100</option>
                                                <option value="4">100-500</option>
                                                <option value="5">500-1000</option>
                                            </select>          
                                   <span id="spGuest" style="color: red;"></span>

  $('#guest').on('change', function () {
            $('#spGuest').empty();
        });
```

Comment: did you add jquery library , as empty method should clear span element.

Comment: there is nothing inside the `<span>` to delete, what are you trying to achieve with the `.empty()`?

Comment: $("#spGuest").empty();
                    $("#spGuest").append("Please select no. of guest");

Comment: i have append message on <span>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you  appnded just text message, and you want to clear that message again just call text method

if you are wrapping your validation error message with html, then you can clear that message ,using html method

```
 $('#spGuest').text('');
    or
 $('#spGuest').html('');
```